# How develop a financial software in Qt?

Tags: database, qt, qt4, finance

I want to create a little finance-software for my association. I want to keep it simple and easy-using, creating new persons should be possible, and every person has entries and costs. The programm should calculate the sum in every step and the total of every person.
Now my question: What is a good way to realize that? I thought about SQLite, which seems easy to realize, but not really perfect (f.e. no secondary keys).

Comment: Consider "using an existing tool" as one definition of "simple".

Comment: @pst: i have special requirements for the software, it should be simple for the user, and no existing tool has every feature i have in mind, so unfortunately this is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is a totally good way to realize that.
You can have one table with names and a PersonalKey as PRIMARY KEY and another table with your bookings, where every booking has also a PersonalKey for the Person, the booking is for.
So you can join the tables and make your SELECTions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) who have more SQL features

Here is some posts about [Firebird and QT](http://www.firebirdnews.org/index.php?s=QT&submit=)